# How to use Alarm Manager to schedule my android app to run in especial time?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am new with android and I wanna make a alarm app that gets a time from user and make android system to run application in that time.Now I calculate the time between current and the entered time and use the following code to sleep app but doesn't work when my app close or even minimized:

```
start_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePicker tp = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timepicker1);
                                int hour = tp.getCurrentHour();
                                int min = tp.getCurrentMinute();

                                Integer res = min + hour*60;

                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                                cur_hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                cur_min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                Integer cur_res = cur_min + cur_hour*60;

                if(cur_res > res)
                {
                    res_min =1440-( cur_res - res);
                }

                else
                {
                    res_min = res-cur_res;
                }

                res_min *= 60000;

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Thread(){

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        super.run();
                            PlayMusic();
                        }

                },res_min);

            }
        });
```

I searched hardly for solution and I find out that Alarm Manager is the answer but I couldn't find a proper code to work in this situation.I'm looking for a simple way to perform that.I don't know if there is a better way or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the AlarmManager? If you have, post the code that you've tried.

Look at the Google Developer API for classes such as these. They are fantastically documented.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

An example:

```
//You must set permissions in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>


//In your code
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), milli, sec, min, pi);
```